# VideoView in different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to insert a video for different sizes of screen. What I want it's a good resolution and without distortion. I have 2 videos for large and tiny screens. But I don't know how to insert them.

I thought it was like insert images from drawables files (hdpi, ldpi, etc) where you add the image in the resolution folder that you want.
But I dont know if happens the same with videos or not.

Please help me to insert both videos to different resolutions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html), as far as Android is concerned is any kind of graphic/image/icon... But a video doesn't fall in that category. For that matter, you'll have to place it at the "./assets/" folder. Therefore, videos aren't automatically selected according to the screen size.

However, even if the videos are in a different folder, you can load them programmatically at the onCreate() method, like this:

```
Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int w = mDisplay.getWidth();
int h = mDisplay.getHeight();

if (w < 480 || h < 800) {
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(...your video in assets, of low resolution...);;
} else {
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(...your video in assets, of high resolution...);
}
...
```

With this or a similar method, you can load different videos, according to the user resolution, in a way that is even more precise than the ldpi/mdpi/etc method.