# Target different screen sizes for VideoView

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-screen

I am developing a splash screen in my application, which includes a VideoView with attributes of fill_parent in either dimension. Now as I know that graphics are rendered differently from different folders at runtime and that this holds true for only images.  I have devised the following code to run based on screen configuration:

```
      Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
      int w = mDisplay.getWidth();
      int h = mDisplay.getHeight();

      if (w < 480 || h < 800) {
         mVideoView.setVideoPath(...your video in assets, of low resolution...);;
      } else {
         mVideoView.setVideoPath(...your video in assets, of high resolution...);
      }
     ...
```

(Reference: [VideoView in different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574612/videoview-in-different-screen-sizes))

Now I want to know which screen sizes are most common and which screen sizes should I support, I want my application to be compatible with most of the devices.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

Use in res/values-xlarge/ with Boolean value

```
<bool name="isTabletDevice">true</bool>
```

In res/values use

```
<bool name="isTabletDevice">false</bool>
```

boolean tabletDeviceSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTabletDevice);

if (tabletDeviceSize) {

```
//use tablet support videoview
```

}
 else

{

```
//use mobile support videoview
```

}

As per android supporting screen

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html,

res/values-sw600dp can also be used.

(for  600dp wide tablet and bigger).

Comment: I will have to check this out.